# multiple canvas on same page

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, canvas

How to load multiple canvas and enable drawing on it
I have two records in database. `foreach` loop below make two canvas but I can only draw in only one canvas not on the both canvas. I should able to draw on both canvas and that is the things I want. I am looking for any help or any tips on  how should I do so that I can draw on all canvas generated dynamically.

```
 <body onload="init()">
    @foreach($imageDrawing as $draw)
     {{$draw->id}}
        <canvas  id="can" width="1200" height="400" 
            style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:2px solid;">
        </canvas>
        
        <input type="text" name="imgage_{{$draw->id}}"
         id="draw_image">
    </body>
    @endforeach
```

Below is the js code that allows user to draw on image of canvas

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
    prevX = 0,
    currX = 0,
    prevY = 0,
    currY = 0,
    dot_flag = false;

var x = "red",
    y = 2;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('can');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;
    //
   
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
    base_image.src = "https://cdn.glitch.com/4c9ebeb9-8b9a-4adc-ad0a-238d9ae00bb5%2Fmdn_logo-only_color.svg?1535749917189"
    base_image.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0,800,400);

  };
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e){
        findxy('move', e)
      
        document.getElementById("draw_image").value =canvas.toDataURL()

    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        findxy('down', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
        findxy('up', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        findxy('out', e)
    }, false);

  

}

function draw() {
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = x;
    ctx.lineWidth = y;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

  

function findxy(res, e) {

    
    if (res == 'down') {
        
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = x;
            ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
            ctx.closePath();
            dot_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
    }
    if (res == 'move') {
        if (flag) {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            currY = e.clientY -canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            draw();

        }
    }

}

</script>
```